# Using a class as an AVAudioPlayerDelegate for a static AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, avaudioplayer, trigger.io

I can't maintain an instance in a TriggerIO plugin, so I need a static way of responding to my `AVAudioPlayer`'s events. However, I can't set the `player.delegate` to `audio_API`, so I'm a bit stuck.

audio_API.h:

```
@interface audio_API : NSObject<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

audio_API.m:

```
static AVAudioPlayer* player = nil;


@implementation audio_API


+ (void)play:(ForgeTask*)task {

    // parse the file url from the file object
    ForgeFile* file = [[ForgeFile alloc] initWithFile:[task.params objectForKey:@"file"]];
    NSString* fileURL = [file url];

    NSLog(@"Playing file at %@", fileURL);

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL];


    // TESTING
    url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"seconds.m4a" withExtension:nil];
    // END TESTING

    NSAssert(url, @"URL is invalid.");

    // create the player
    NSError* error = nil;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if(!player)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
    };

//    player.delegate = audio_API;

    [player play];

    [task success:nil];
}


+ (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {
        [ForgeLog d:@"Audio finished playing successfully."];
    } else {
        [ForgeLog d:@"Audio did not finish playing successfully."];
    }

    // call the audio.finishedPlaying event
    [[ForgeApp sharedApp] event:@"audio.finishedPlaying" withParam:nil];
}

+ (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
    [ForgeLog d:@"Audio had error decoding."];
    [ForgeLog e:error];

    // call the audio.decodeErrorOccurred event
    [[ForgeApp sharedApp] event:@"audio.decodeErrorOccurred" withParam:nil];
}

@end
```

Any idea of how to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem when you try to set the delegate?

Comment: `/Users/gsquare567/forge-workspace/plugins/audio/inspector/ios-inspector/ForgeModule/alert/audio_API.m:47:23: Unexpected interface name 'audio_API': expected expression` when I try `player.delegate = audio_API;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate has to be an object, but `audio_API` is type name. However, you can simply assign the delegate to be the class object of `audio_API`:

```
player.delegate = (id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>)[audio_API class];
```

Note: If you don't cast the class object the compiler will complain, because `[audio_API class]` returns a `Class`, not a `Class<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`, even if you specify the delegate on the interface for `audio_API`

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped making my class that manages the sound an AVAudioPlayerDelegate.
SoundManager.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface SoundManager : NSObject<AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

}
```

and in the .m file you can optionally implement callbacks for the delegate like e.g.:

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying %d",flag);
}
```